# How to understand "that he had come to dread" in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense

> "Ray," she said in that whispery conspirator's voice that he had come to dread.  "Ray, listen --"

I saw the sentence in a book, The Long Walk.  The usage of that that-clause confuses me.  Is it modifying the noun word **voice**? I think the sentence is saying *her whispery conspirator's voice made him come to dread*.  Is my understanding correct? And, why does it use the perfect tense？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It applies to the entire phrase "whispery conspirator's voice", not just "voice". Presumably, he doesn't dread her voice in general, just when she whispers in a conspiratorial tone.
 The perfect tense is used because it is describing a reaction he had come to have after hearing that tone in the past, when it had been associated with some difficulty.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence structure.  Normally, I'd expect "such... that..." structure for this, like *she said in such whispery conspirator's voice that he had come to dread.*

Comment: @dan "That" in "that whisper conspirator's voice" is a determiner, as in "that cat" or "that car". The second "that" is a relative pronoun and a relative clause marker. Clear now?

Comment: @EddieKal Not really.  I understand its a relative pronoun, but what the relative clause is doing there?

Comment: @EddieKal Can we understand it as "he had come to dread in that whispery conspirator's voice"?

Comment: @dan  No. It is "that (determiner) whispery conspirator's voice" (noun phrase) that (subordinator followed by relative clause) he had come to dread".  It means she used a particular voice, the one he had come to dread.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Normally, the noun or noun phrase takes a role in the relative clause.  E. g.  This is the book that I like.  "That I like" modifies "the book". (I like the book).  But in this case, "the whispery conspirator's voice" doesn't seem to take any part in the relative clause(he had come to dread), does it?

Comment: No, it's the head of the relative clause. "That whispery conspirator's voice" is equivalent to the word "book" in your example.

Comment: Let's simplify it. "the voice that he dreaded" is parallel to "the book that I like". Now, substitute "that whispery conspirator's voice" for "the voice", and "that he had come to dread" for "that he dreaded". The structure is the same, it's just more descriptive.

Comment: @dan Jack's latest comment is what it is. I may not have phrased it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The first "that" is just a determiner, as Eddie Kal says in the comments. Compare these examples:

> She said [something] in *that* manner.
>   You are not going to solve anything with *that* attitude.
>   Hit him in the head with *that* bottle.

Now break the original down:

> She said "Ray" in *that* [whispery conspirator's voice] **that (or which)** he had come to dread.

If you rephrase it, it would be something like this:

> She said "Ray" in a manner **that** he doesn't like. (You can replace "that" here with "which" to actually understand its purpose)

I think Jack's answer pretty much covers the "perfect tense" part.

Comment: Normally, the noun or noun phrase takes a role in the relative clause.  E. g.  This is the book that I like.  "That I like" modifies "the book". (I like the book).  But in this case, "the whispery conspirator's voice" doesn't seem to take any part in the relative clause(he had come to dread), does it?

Comment: @dan It does. "**that** he had come to dread" modifies "*that* whispery ... voice". There may be more than one type of whispery voice, but he dreads a specific one. She said it in *that* whispery voice, which he dreads.